# How I can fetch data from get request using angular 2 pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried more than one time to get data through api request using pipe. It return object object. Could you please help me to solve these problem.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'member'
})

export class MemberNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {}

  transform(value: any): any {
    if(value == undefined) return value; 
      return this.apiService.getMemberName(value).subscribe(
        data => {return data.data},
        err => {console.log(err)}
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: pipes are for data transformation.  It is a poor architectural design to have a pipe that returns data which is fundamentally different from the input.

Comment: @Claies is correct - pipes are to transform existing data. I think you'd want to have a component that loads the data from the ApiService, then use a pipe to transform how that data is displayed in your component template.

Comment: I need to display data inside table using *ngFor. Instead of Member Id i want to display Member Name

Comment: @Abdulaziz, for this you need no pipe. Just make the api call and display the name in the template. How does your response look like?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at `AyncPipe` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html

If you still want to use normal pipe then you should pre-load the data from server and use it inside your pipe.